# Why do my letters go up and down as I type in a UITextView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

Here's a gif of the behavior:

[image]

I want the text to stay in place, without going up and down as demonstrated.

Here's the actual UITextView:

```
let chatTextField: UITextView = {
    let chatText = UITextView()
    chatText.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 16)
    chatText.backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 248, g: 248, b: 248)
    chatText.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return chatText
}()
```

My text view is inside a container so here is how I constrained it:

```
self.chatTextField.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(container.heightAnchor).active = true
self.chatTextField.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(212).active = true
self.chatTextField.centerYAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(container.centerYAnchor).active = true
self.chatTextField.centerXAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(container.centerXAnchor).active = true
```

I'm not sure whether this is a bug or a constraint problem, but I have an idea that it could be the text leading, or other font attributes.

Comment: I finally got it. It's because somewhere in my logic, my scrolling is getting enabled and disabled.